# JSON Parsing Value Not Showing

Tags: c#, json, json.net

So I am using `JSON.net` to parse my JSON, but I get wrong output for a `List of List` **Values** object. Here's my JSON.net code:

```
var reader = new StreamReader(GenerateStreamFromString(decodedString));
            var rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(reader.ReadToEnd());

txtOut.Text = rootObject.Results.output1.value.ColumnNames[0].ToString() + " : " + 
rootObject.Results.output1.value.Values[0].ToString();
```

Here are the JSON Classes:

```
public class Value
{
    public List<string> ColumnNames { get; set; }
    public List<string> ColumnTypes { get; set; }
    public List<List<string>> Values { get; set; }
}

public class Output1
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public Value value { get; set; }
}

public class Results
{
    public Output1 output1 { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Results Results { get; set; }
}
```

The output should be:

```
Scored Probabilities for Class "BackPocket" : 0.37687685364
```

While I get:

```
Scored Probabilities for Class "BackPocket" : System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]
```

Where have I done wrong?

Thanks.

P.S. Here is a sample JSON:

```
{"Results":{"output1":{"type":"table","value":{"ColumnNames":["Scored Probabilities for Class \"BackPocket\"","Scored Probabilities for Class \"Ear\"","Scored Probabilities for Class \"Handbag\"","Scored Probabilities for Class \"SidePocket\"","Scored Labels"],"ColumnTypes":["Double","Double","Double","Double","String"],"Values":[["0.0249993801116943","0.999469399452209","0.00426889630034566","0.00104729761369526","Ear"]]}}}}
```

Comment: Your json is not valid. Check it at http://json2csharp.com/#

Comment: Why should it be the first value instead of the `List`? You have a list of lists after all, so you need to specify which element of that "secondary" list you want

Comment: @ShannonHolsinger Just checked and corrected.

Comment: @UnholySheep How do I access the list of the list without writing a `foreach` loop? It seems that's where I am stuck.

Comment: It is a list of lists.  You're currently only indexing one level deep.  You need to index two levels deep. `Values[0][0]`

Comment: @DavidL Bingo! Solved. Please write it s that I can mark it as answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Jeet.Deir happy to, see below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a list of lists. You're currently only indexing one level deep. You need to index two levels deep.

```
txtOut.Text = rootObject.Results.output1.value.ColumnNames[0].ToString() + " : " + 
rootObject.Results.output1.value.Values[0][0].ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Because element 0 is a list, You can use `string.Join` to get a printable string..

```
txtOut.Text = rootObject.Results.output1.value.ColumnNames[0].ToString() + " : " +
                string.Join(";",rootObject.Results.output1.value.Values[0]);
```

OUTPUT would be:

```
Scored Probabilities for Class "BackPocket" : 0.0249993801116943;0.999469399452209;0.00426889630034566;0.00104729761369526;Ear
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this as your Json Class/Classes

```
[DataContract]    
public class Value
{
[DataMember]
public List<string> ColumnNames { get; set; }
[DataMember]
public List<string> ColumnTypes { get; set; }
[DataMember]
public List<List<string>> Values { get; set; }
}
[DataContract]
public class Output1
{
[DataMember]
public string type { get; set; }
[DataMember]
public Value value { get; set; }
}
[DataContract]
public class Results
{
[DataMember]
public Output1 output1 { get; set; }
}
[DataContract]
public class RootObject
{
[DataMember]
public Results Results { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, they're added automatically -- just making sure his Json was correct, because I t wasn't when OP first posted.